# How to steer an ML model to pick up on a pattern

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-learn to train an ML model to pick up on date patterns.

For the features portion, it will be a list of lists containing the following: [# of "/" in row, # of "-" in row, length of row]

An example row would be "12/12/12" or "12-12-12".

For the labels, it will be binary (1 = date, 0 = not date).

The issue that I am having is that the model is not picking up on the "length of row" portion of the features list. What I mean by this is that at any instance the model has 2 "/" or "-", it will be classified as a date regardless of the length of the entire row. So when I predicted the following "[2,0,0]", it would still classify it as a date.

I used the about 15k rows to train the dates (work csv file, all different formats of dates) and I used about 8-9k rows of phone numbers (global phone numbers, of various lengths) to train what not to match as dates.

As for the actual ML model, since this is a classification problem, I tried using Decision Trees, Random Forests, as well as KNN classifiers. While the models accuracy_score was close to 100%, when I predicted "[2,0,0]", it returned this as a date when it should not be classified as a date (impossible to have a row with 2 "/" but a total row length of 0).

Any help would be great!

Comment: What?  Where are you getting your "/"s from? I don't see them in the example string you provided.  What is a row?

Comment: @NathanielSaul Probably should have been more specific. A row would contain something like this: "12/12/12" or "12-12-12". Will update my original post.

Comment: Maybe you could have different columns for each entry of the string?

Comment: @rmahesh Okay, is there a reason you're trying to use an ML model?  It seems like a deterministic method like [dateutil.parse](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) would work better for you?

Comment: @kilojoules I am quite new to this, and I am not sure how exactly I would go about doing that.

Comment: @NathanielSaul I actually solved this exact problem using regex, but my work wants me to solve this using Machine Learning algorithms.

Comment: Also, it's totally reasonable to do some feature engineering before giving your data to the model.  Something like @kilojoules mentioned is great. You could also have a column that is just the count of the delimiters, one for "/" and one for "-", one for others.

Comment: If it is really just because you works want you to do it, then create a column that is the result of the regex and use that to train the model.

Comment: Here's a nice looking tutorial on feature engineering http://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/

Comment: @NathanielSaul That is an interesting way of looking at it, I never thought of it like that. I don't know if this code can include the regex but I will explore this. Thank you for the link, I will be sure to check that out!